# how to not select lookbehind word in javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

```
My regex: <br>![a-z]+(?=<br>)

fooword1<br>!fooword2<br>fooword3
```

I am trying to get word that begins with `"!"`, like `"!fooword2"` and exists between `<br>` tags. But when i apply this  `<br>![a-z]+(?=<br>)` , i get `"<br>!fooword2".`
I just need to select   `"!fooword2"` .I mean i don't need to select first `<br>`.

So what is wrong with my regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since JS does not support LookBehind, You could use groups to exclude the first `<br>`

```js
var String = "fooword1<br>!fooword2<br>fooword3";
var Regexp = /<br>(![a-z]+\d)<br>/g;
var match = Regexp.exec(String);
console.log(match[1])
```

Another option will be using Positive Lookahead at the end with `<br>`, and relying on the `!` at the beginning:

```
![a-z]+\d(?=<br>)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/kRzoQB/3

Comment: one more question : why do i still get matched Word even if i change the first "<br>" with "<brrrrrrrr>" like "fooword1<brrrrrrrr>!fooword2<br>fooword3". but when i change second <br> tag like the first one then it doesnt match. As a result i dont want it selected if <br> tags changed....https://regex101.com/r/CsX7lg/1

Comment: @sommeguyy I did couple tests with Negative Lookahead, and it does not seem reliable in your case. I would recommend that you use the first method. It will get you exactly the string that is between `<br>` if it starts with `!`

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
<br>(![a-z0-9]+)<br>
```

as a regex?

Answer (score 0):

This might work better. It doesn't depend on the tag that is used.

```
var str = 'fooword1<br>!fooword2<br>fooword3',
      regi = /(!\w*\d{1})/g,
      obj = regi.exec(str);

console.log(obj[0]);
```

You need the [0] because exec returns an array and the value that you are looking for is at the zero index of that array.